# Uniquely split using two columns (character variables)

Tags: r

I have two columns (variable with characters) and the rest variables are numeric. I want to uniquely split the data using the two column variables (characters)  and hoping to find a list and then want to use lapply, how do I go about that?

```
library (stringr)
data1<- data[,4]
data_PS <-str_split_fixed (data$P, data$S, n= inf)
data_SP<- split(data1, data_PS)

At this stage, I am expecting something like the following, but I couldn't:
$B01A AB

0.004207584

$B01A AB

0.909964792
..........
```

the data under data is:

```
    P   S   Y   C
B01A    AB  89  0.004207584
B01A    AB  56  0.909964792
B01A    AC  75  0.954100983
B01A    AC  59  0.188894002
B01A    AD  54  0.509861629
B01C    BC  55  0.836337726
B01C    BD  96  0.672129146
B01C    BB  97  0.497534214
A02A    CA  99  0.125507057
A02A    CA  97  0.983640234
A02A    CB  99  0.672362232
A02A    CB  57  0.865594553
A02A    CD  96  0.395702416
```

Comment: Do you need `split(df$C, df$P)` ?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, thanks ! I need both P and S, because it is the two variables that uniquely identify because two of the same P have different combination, i.e,  B01A of P is combined to AB and AC of S, so, I need both P and S variables to uniquely identify and then C?

Comment: `split(df$C, list(df$P, df$S))` Or `split(df, list(df$P, df$S))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two columns into one and then use split on that column.

```
df$groups <- paste(df$P, df$S, sep="_")
split_data <- split(df$C, df$groups)
```

Comment: thanks to all and that can easily works for me, if I have like 50 data points in each split and I want to do a loop in each split, dividing 40 as training set and 10 as testing set and develop a model from each split and finally bring all of them together, how can I go about that? I will appreciate for that! I wanted to post another question but it is a continuation of this one?

Comment: probably a different question would be the best

Answer (score 2):

We can use `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_split(P, S)
```